# jQuery - Selecting active dots for li's and removing active class from others

Tags: jquery, html

I have a side navigation ul menu with a series of li's, for demonstrative purposes at the moment.

The first automatically uses the activeDot class, and when another is clicked the new dot uses this class, removing the class from the previously selected dot, but I have a problem where once a new dot uses the activeDot class and another dot is clicked on, the class isn't then removed from the previously-clicked dot. Only one dot should be active at a time, which I have tried to implement into my jQuery.

EDIT: Okay, now I've found out the jQuery isn't actually working at all in JSFiddle even though it's the same code.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lusru678/.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var currentDot = $('#aboutSideNav > ul > li.activeDot');

    $('#aboutSideNav > ul > li').click(function() {

        $(this).addClass('activeDot');
        currentDot.removeClass('activeDot');

    });  

    $('#aboutSideNav > ul > li.activeDot').click(function() {

        $(this).addClass('activeDot');

    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="aboutSideNav" class="sideNav" style="margin-top:-100px">

    <ul>

        <li class="activeDot"></li>

        <li></li>

        <li></li>

        <li></li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sideNav
{
position:absolute;
width:auto;
top:0;
right:0;
height:100%;
z-index:99;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
}

.sideNav > ul
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.sideNav > ul > li
{
position:relative;
display:block;
margin:25px 30px;
width:4px;
height:4px;
cursor:pointer;
background:#fff;
border:2px solid #fff;
border-radius:50%;
transition:all linear 0.3s;
-webkit-transition:all linear 0.3s;
-moz-transition:all linear 0.3s;
}

@media only screen
and (max-width: 768px)
{
.sideNav > ul > li
{
    width:8px;
    height:8px;
}
}

.sideNav > ul > li.activeDot
{
background:transparent;
}

.sideNav > ul > li:hover
{
background:transparent;
border:2px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: btw @nickck15, you can activate jQuery easily in jsfiddle by clicking on the "javascript" gear icon, it allows to add any common library easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only need one more line to make

> Only one dot should be active at a time

happen

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var currentDot = $('#aboutSideNav > ul > li.activeDot');

$('#aboutSideNav > ul > li').click(function() {
    $('li.activeDot').removeClass('activeDot'); // this line
    $(this).addClass('activeDot');
   // currentDot.removeClass('activeDot');//no longer needed

});  

  /*  $('#aboutSideNav > ul > li.activeDot').click(function() {

    $(this).addClass('activeDot'); // this li has class activeDot - why do you need this?

   });*/

});
```

and now as a one liner

```
 $('#aboutSideNav > ul > li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('activeDot').siblings().removeClass('activeDot'); 
})
```

> The original element is not included among the siblings, which is important to remember when we wish to find all elements at a particular level of the DOM tree

from https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: you did not include jquery, look here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lusru678/14/ (changed link)

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var currentDot = $('#aboutSideNav > ul > li.activeDot');

    $('#aboutSideNav ul li').click(function() {

        $(this).addClass('activeDot');
        $('#aboutSideNav ul li').not(this).removeClass('activeDot');

    });  



});
```

Comment: can you please provide the link of jsfiddle ?

Comment: this is also working i have tested . anyway glad that one solution is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Given the above requirements, I'd suggest:

```
// binding the anonymous function of the on() method as the
// 'click' event-handler:
$('#aboutSideNav > ul > li').on('click', function(){

  // adds the activeDot class to the clicked element,
  // removes the activeDot class from all sibling elements:
  $(this).addClass('activeDot').siblings().removeClass('activeDot');
});
```

A massively simplified demo (reducing the over-specificity of the selectors, and also the bizarre use of the `style` attribute in the `#aboutSideNave` element which hides most of the `<li>` elements for no apparent reason):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var currentDot = $('#aboutSideNav > ul > li.activeDot');

  $('#aboutSideNav > ul > li').click(function() {

    $(this).addClass('activeDot');
    currentDot.removeClass('activeDot');

  });

  $('#aboutSideNav > ul > li.activeDot').click(function() {

    $(this).addClass('activeDot');

  });

});
```

```css
li {
  display: block;
  margin: 25px 30px;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all linear 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all linear 0.3s;
}
li.activeDot {
  background-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aboutSideNav" class="sideNav">

  <ul>

    <li class="activeDot"></li>

    <li></li>

    <li></li>

    <li></li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lusru678/17/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: Really? Because, when simplified it works perfectly well for me; I suspect part of the problem is the over-specificity of your CSS selectors, and the (frankly weird) use of the `style` attribute hiding most of the `<li>` elements in your linked demo. Incidentally, also in your demo, you didn't link to jQuery, which is possibly why it didn't work when you tried it (JavaScript isn't magical, it doesn't guess what library you meant to use).